# Cannot access sub object of returned JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I might just be blind or something, but I really cannot figure out why I cannot access a sub object of a returned $Resource object that retrieved a bunch of JSON objects.

```
Resource
> $resolved: true
> $then: function (b, g) {var j=e(),h=
> data: Object
  > 519bc5f6b2427a732be1c360: Object
```

The raw JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "519bc5f6b2427a732be1c360": {
            "id": "519bc5f6b2427a732be1c360",
            "planning": {
                "id": "519bc5f6b2427a732be1c355"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain me why this doesn't work:

```
var training = Training.query()

console.log(training); // returns the entire $Resource
console.log(training.data); // returns: undefined
```

Comment: A scientific guess: http://felix-kling.de/blog/2011/08/18/inspecting-variables-in-javascript-consoles/ PS: If I were you I would put a break (just a regular one or using `debugger;`) and check with debugger what is the actual value (that's right, you can trust a debugger, and you cannot trust `console.log()`)

Comment: `.query()` returns an array

Comment: @user1737909 Good point, but that's already solved in my services layer, didn't add that; I have manually set .query() to return isArray: false;

Comment: Because you are missing a closing }?

Comment: omg, instead of checking and getting the data for sure you guys prefer continue guessing.......... It's so weird way to program, really

Comment: No the missing } was a typo, my bad. Edited.

Comment: @zerkms I tried the debugger; function, but that prevented the REST call from completing and returned a $resolved = false;, which made the data incomplete to begin with.

Comment: @Bjorn Schijff: isn't that an answer then? At the moment you was trying to access the data there were no data fetched yet

Comment: Yes that was the conclusion I draw right after; the closure function solved it because it's a callback, thus only reacts when there is a response to begin with. I didn't know the $resource object would be there if there was a response or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting the data like this:

```
var training = Training.query(function($val) {
    console.log($val);
    console.log($val.data);
});
```

Comment: This works! I've got another problem now, but I might be able to figure this out. Thank you for your contribution!

The closure function seemed to work for some reason, but I still deem this weird and unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the explanation - from [the Angular docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource):

> It is important to realize that invoking a $resource object method immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on isArray). Once the data is returned from the server the existing reference is populated with the actual data. This is a useful trick since usually the resource is assigned to a model which is then rendered by the view. Having an empty object results in no rendering, once the data arrives from the server then the object is populated with the data and the view automatically re-renders itself showing the new data. This means that in most case one never has to write a callback function for the action methods.

So this works:

```js
var training = Training.query(function(value){
  // this is the callback function
  console.log(training === value); // true - it's the same object
  console.log(training.data); // and now it has data
});
```